# Grails 5 application fails to start up with an error related to spring/resources.groovy

Tags: grails

I am upgrading a grails 2.x application to Grails 5. During start up there is a ClassCastException and it just says resources cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Script. Why would this happen? Is there a solution to get around this problem?

Stack Trace:
org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Error loading spring/resources.groovy file: resources cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Script

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the usage of PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource in resource.groovy. In older versions of grails, this class was available under the package - org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource

But Grails5 has it under org.grails.spring.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource